# How to display links with one-to-many relationships using Formtastic and ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

I have a one-to-many relationship (Stories have many Surveys).  How can I cause the "index" and "show" pages to display links to Surveys rather than text (as they currently display)?

```
ActiveAdmin.register Story do
  actions :all

  form do |f|
    f.inputs
    f.buttons
  end

  index do
    column :surveys
    default_actions
  end

  show do
    attributes_table do
      row :surveys
    end
    active_admin_comments
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
...
column 'Surveys' do |story|
  story.surveys.map { |survey|
    link_to survey.name, admin_survey_path(survey)
  }.join("<br/>").html_safe
end

...
row 'Surveys' do |story|
  story.surveys.map { |survey| 
    link_to survey.name, admin_survey_path(survey)
  }.join("<br/>").html_safe
end
```

Comment: Thanks!  Just needed to change "survey_path" to "admin_survey_path" for your code to work.